# Namespace in PHP CodeIgniter Framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, namespaces

Does CodeIgniter support Namespace?

Comment: A better question to ask is why do you need them? I generally "namespace" code with prefixes or suffixes. For example, $this->user_lib or $this->user_m means you wont clash with anything else. I'd REALLY like CI to support Controller_Foo but thats not gonna happen soon :-/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Namespace are supported by php and not by the framework (codeigniter in your case). If you use namespaces php version must be >= 5.3.0
Codeigniter dosen`t use namespaces because it is written to support php 4.

Comment: Here is a workaround found: http://porquero.blogspot.com/2012/03/codeigniter-hmvc-namespaces-part-1.html

Answer (score 35):

## How To Get Namespaces to Work in Codeigniter

Actually, you can get namespaces to work in conjunction to relative paths in your application models. This modification makes loading models much easier and also allows you to have interfaces...

**Add this to the end of your application/config/config.php**

```
spl_autoload_extensions('.php'); // Only Autoload PHP Files

spl_autoload_register(function($classname) {
    if (strpos($classname,'\\') !== false) {
        // Namespaced Classes
        $classfile = strtolower(str_replace('\\', '/', $classname));

        if ($classname[0] !== '/') {
            $classfile = APPPATH.'models/' . $classfile . '.php';
        }               
        require($classfile);
    } elseif (strpos($classname, 'interface') !== false) {
        // Interfaces
        strtolower($classname);
        require('application/interfaces/' . $classname . '.php');
    }
});
```

**Example Namespaced Class:**

```
<?php
// File: application/models/foo/bar.php
namespace foo;

class Bar extends \CI_Model implements \Awesome_interface {

    public $foobar;

    public function __construct() {
        return parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getFoobar() {
        return $this->foobar;
    }

    public function setFoobar($val) {
        $this->foobar = $val;
    }

}
```

**Example Instantiation of Class in Your Code Somewhere:**

***IMPORTANT NOTE:*** DO NOT USE BUILT IN CI_Loader ( Ex: $this->load->model(); )

```
// This will Autoload Your Namespaced Class
$example = new foo\Bar();
```

or alternatively on top of your PHP class (ex: controller, other model), you can do this...

```
<?php
...
use foo\Bar as FooBar;

...

// Then you can just do this
$example = new FooBar();
```

**Example of Interface:**

```
<?php
// File: application/interfaces/awesome_interface.php
interface Awesome_interface {

    public function getFoobar();

}
```

Comment: after a couple of changes to the `spl_autoload_register` method classes load without error. Thx

Comment: @TimothyPerez Is there any other way to load libraries having namespace in CodeIgniter 3 ?

Comment: @JunaidQadirShekhanzai _after a couple of changes_  ? What changes did you make ?

Comment: It's been years and I don't remember. Sorry

Comment: 3.x supports namespaces. I have moved to Laravel

Answer (score 5):

Just a simple psr-4 autoloading and you are done.

In the `config/config.php` load composer using

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = FCPATH.'vendor/autoload.php';
```

In the root directory run `composer install`
In the generated `composer.json` add following lines for psr4 autoloading.

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "application/"
        }
    },
```

`App` would be your namespace in this case.

Example: suppose you have a class `Service` in libraries folder. You can namespace it with:

```
<?php
namespace App\libraries;

class Service{
}
```

Use it in `Welcome` controller class:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use App\libraries\Service;
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check this out: [yidas/codeigniter-psr4-autoload](https://github.com/yidas/codeigniter-psr4-autoload)

The lib defines `app` as CI application root so that every classes in application could be loaded with PSR-4 namespace:

```
\app\libraries\MemberService::auth();
\app\helpers\ArrayHelper::indexBy($input);
\app\widgets\StatWidget::run();
class Blog_model extends app\core\BaseModel {}
class Car_model implements app\contracts\CarInterface {}
```

Sample code for defining a class:

```
<?php
namespace app\helpers;
class ArrayHelper
{
    public static function indexBy($input) {}
}
```

> https://github.com/yidas/codeigniter-psr4-autoload

Answer (score -1):

add the line below in a class that you want to use goutte`

```
require __DIR__ . "/../../../vendor/autoload.php";
```

and in absolute path of your project run   :`composer

```
require fabpot/goutte
```

to add goutte in your package.json file. now all things should work well.`