# Cannot find class in vendor folder codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php

I am trying to use the invoice generator from [webchemistry](https://github.com/WebChemistry/invoice). I installed this with `composer require webchemistry/invoice:^1.0`.

I moved this folder to my `APPPATH . 'third_party\vendor\';` folder. So in my config file I have the following line:

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = APPPATH . 'third_party\vendor\autoload.php';
```

my index.php file (in root) contains this code:

```
include_once BASEPATH.'../application/third_party/vendor/autoload.php';
```

In my controller I am trying to do the following :

```
public function createInvoice()
{
    $company = new \WebChemistry\Invoice\Data\Company();
}
```

This results in the following error:

> Message: Class 'WebChemistry\Invoice\Data\Company' not found

When in my IDE (PhpStorm) I ctrl + click on Company, it can resolve correctly and points to the correct file. 
Why can PHP not resolve this to the correct file location?

Comment: try `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: It said Generating autoload files but all errors remained the same

Comment: My answer here might be of some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49461123/how-do-i-include-the-oop-defiant-randomdotorg-library-in-codeigniter/49461228#49461228

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the file include and following code in your controller at the start

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = false; // no need change this, make it default

<?php
require_once(APPPATH . '/third_party/vendor/autoload.php');
use \WebChemistry\Invoice\Data\Company as Company;

class Invoice extends CI_Controller {

    public function createInvoice(){
        $company = new Company();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have run it and check and i have seen to many deprecated error message from the library file : 
`Replace deprecated Nette\Object with trait Nette\SmartObject `

Answer (score 1):

You should not do anything with `vendor` directory unless you know what you're doing. If you want to change directory where Composer installs dependencies, you can do this by setting [`vendor-dir`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#vendor-dir) in `composer.json` config:

```
{
    ...
    "config":{
        "vendor-dir": "third_party/vendor"
    }
}
```