# How to fix Class not found when using entity class? How to show database in object?

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, entity

I was trying a tutorial from another place to show my data from an instance object. But when i try to implement it, i found error 
Message: Class 'Booking' not found
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\teja\application\controllers\controlBooking.php

this is my code in class Booking

```
<?php namespace application\classes;
class Booking {
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $address;
public function setId(string $id){
    $this->id = $id;
}
public function getId(){
    return $this->id;
}
public function get_booking()
{
    $query = $this->db->select("*")
             ->from('booking')
             ->order_by('id', 'DESC')
             ->get();
    return $query->result();
}...
```

And this is my model class

```
<?php use application\classes\Booking;
class modelBooking extends CI_Model{
    public function get_all(){
        $book = new Booking();
        $testimoni->get_booking();
    }
}
```

and this is my controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class controlBooking extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct(){
    parent ::__construct();
    //load model
    $this->load->model('modelBooking'); 
}
public function index(){
    $data = new Booking();
    $this->load->view('viewBooking', $data);
}
```

then how i show it in my view class? how to fix that error? 
thankyou for all of you, please help me to solve this

Comment: Does your application use any sort of autoloading? For CodeIgniter see [this guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html).

Comment: @JiriHrazdil when i add $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'classes'); still found an error: Unable to load the requested class: Classes. how do i add an autoloading for my class?

Comment: In the model what is the object `$testimoni`? It is not defined anywhere we can see. Also, what do you do with `$book` created with `$book = new Booking();`?

Comment: @DFriend sorry it was my typo, i mean `$book->get_booking();` after i created `$book = new Booking();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the file *Booking.php* should be moved to the folder `/application/libraries/`

Then, instead of using `new`, use the standard CodeIgniter library loading scheme, e.g.

```
$this->load->library('booking');
```

The CodeIgniter 'Loader' (ie. `$this->load->...`) will locate the class file (if it is in the right place), `include` it, and instantiate the named class.

Wherever you want to use the instance created by the above use

```
$this->booking->some_method();
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter won't autoload namespaced classes out of the box (that I'm aware of), and isn't designed to be used like you would in Laravel or Symphony (entities don't really exist). I highly doubt the tutorial you followed was CI specific.

This will change in CI 4 which is currently in beta testing.

For now, I would suggest either making it a library as DFriend suggested and loosing all the `use` and `namespace` declarations and just loading it the CI way or you can follow along with my answer here: [How do I include the OOP "defiant randomdotorg" library in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49461123/how-do-i-include-the-oop-defiant-randomdotorg-library-in-codeigniter/49461228#49461228)

Please note: whether you are using a library or the above method you cannot access `$this->db` or anything CI-related directly as you would in a model or controller. You'd have to do:

```
$CI = &get_instance;
$CI->db->get(...);
```

obviously the get instance part can be done in the class constructor and assigned to a variable for usage in multiple functions.

Comment: thankyou verymuch! now i can get my code running
but, if i want to put my data from database in settter getter method like:
`$this->booking->setName(take from database);` how can i do that??

Comment: im not sure what you want to do, make a new question.