# How to load a library from composer?

Tags: codeigniter, composer-php, loading

I load a composer library suited for CodeIgniter called `SteeveDroz\Asset`, that I can access without problem with `$asset = new SteeveDroz\Asset`.

I would like to be able to load it with CodeIgniter `$this->load->library('SteeveDroz\Asset')`, but I get the error message

> Unable to load requested class: SteeveDroz\Asset

Is it possible to achieve what I want? If yes, how?

Comment: if the current answer doesn't help, you can try my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49461123/how-do-i-include-the-oop-defiant-randomdotorg-library-in-codeigniter/49461228#49461228 just upvote it if it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned Alex in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56556557/how-to-load-a-library-from-composer?noredirect=1#comment99694886_56557081), it is required to make an adapter library. I created an all purpose class for that:

## application/libraries/ComposerAdapter.php

```
class ComposerAdapter
{
    private $object;

    public function __construct($object)
    {
        $this->object = $object;
    }

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array([$this->object, $method], $args);
    }
}
```

## application/libraries/Asset.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require('ComposerAdapter.php');

class Asset extends ComposerAdapter
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(new SteeveDroz\Asset());
    }
}
```

## application/config/autoload.php

```
// ...
$autoload['libraries'] = array('asset');
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks ;-) I gladly put a MIT license on it! Take it and make it yours!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using CodeIgniter 3 you can modify `application/config/config.php` and set

`$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE`

or

`$config['composer_autoload'] = FCPATH .'vendor/autoload.php';`

this will automatically load all your composer dependencies.

Comment: I already did that (that's why the part with the `new` works), but I still can't use `$this->steevedroz\asset->something()`.

Comment: calling it that would never work, you'd have to make an adapter library (see this smarty one for reference: https://github.com/Vheissu/Ci-Smarty/blob/master/libraries/MY_Parser.php) to interface CI and that code which is completely unnecessary. just init it like you would any other php class `new class();`