# implement goutte in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, goutte

everyone, this is my first question since I join StackOverflow. sorry if my English isn't good. now I'm doing some task using Codeigniter. this task required scraping function. when I am googling, I find this https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte. I still confuse how to implement goutte into Codeigniter. I already install composer and run

```
composer require fabpot/goutte
```

and I created a controller and name it with Scraping.php. the code like this

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use Goutte\Client;

class Scraping extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {

      $client = new Client();
       $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.agoda.com/hotel-eucalyptus/hotel/santorini-gr.html'); 
       $crawler->filter('.FirstTileContent__Header')->each(function ($node) {
          dump($node->text());
      });

    }
}
```

but the result is

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Class 'Goutte\Client' not found
```

and in confuse how should I fix it. please.

Comment: did you try to `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: what version of codeigniter do you have?

Comment: did you tried this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700626/namespace-in-php-codeigniter-framework

Comment: no not yet. but what is that for? after i read you commant. i tried it. but the result is same.

Comment: im using 3.2.0-dev version

Comment: codeigniter is not supporting fully namespaces as it should, so try this https://packagist.org/packages/yidas/codeigniter-psr4-autoload

Comment: i already tried that psr4. but when i test it. it display error message like this "Message: Class 'yidas\Psr4Autoload' not found". now i can't access my site

Comment: have checked this [link](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html), or for testing you can add `require __DIR__ . "/../../vendor/autoload.php";` in the begining of your controller.