# 'Use' not working in Codeigniter Api in PHP

Tags: php, api

I am working with Web services/Api in codeigniter,I want to integrate "Razorpay" Account
so for this i am trying to integrate "Razorpay" source code
But i am getting error "syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)"
Here is my code

```
function razorpayApi_post()
{
    include 'razorpay/Razorpay.php';
    use Razorpay\Api\Api;
    $api_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $api_secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $api = new Api($api_key, $api_secret);
}
```

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: instead of `use Razorpay\Api\Api;` try `$className = new Razorpay(); $function Name = $className->api();`

Comment: Here is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700626/namespace-in-php-codeigniter-framework

Comment: @Gulshan: i am using codeignter version 3

Comment: Namespace are supported by php and not by the framework (Codeigniter in your case). If you use namespaces php version must be >= 5.3.0 Codeigniter doesn't use namespaces because it is written to support php 4.

Comment: @Gulshan:Sir, What should i do then ? please correct/write code so i can check and implment in my side

Comment: try it with `class` instead of `namespace`

Comment: @Gulshan: Can you explain please

Comment: Here is a github repo https://github.com/MazahirHaroon/Razorpay-Subscription-Codeigniter-

Comment: I have attached js url. You can include this url and make object for it.
https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js
$className = new Razorpay();

Comment: @Gulshan: i tried same as their controller , means i added following two lines ( upload razopray in assets folder) 

require_once ('assets\razorpay\Razorpay.php');
use Razorpay\Api\Api as RazorpayApi;

But i am getting following error 

"  require_once(assets\razorpay\Razorpay.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Comment: @RuchiPatel: should i use "include" or "require" method also ? and can i use this file for "create account" and for "transfer" api ?